# How to change from exact url to subsite in customsearch.ai?

Tags: search, azure-cognitive-services, bing

How do I change a url from an exact url to a subsite in the https://www.customsearch.ai? I add a url but it automatically chooses exact url?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to change the search in the right-side to bing, then Search bing, find the page, then add the page as a subsite.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add http or https in the URL and it will be configured as 'site'. If you add http or https to the URL, it will be configured as 'exact URL'.